# UIPageViewController not resizing its child view controllers on rotation

Tags: ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller, screen-orientation, autolayout

I am trying to use UIPageViewController with view controllers added to it, problem is if I launch the app in portrait mode it appears perfectly like this:

[image]

but if I rotate the device to landscape mode it appears like this:

[image]

Though pagination control has resized properly, view of added view controller has not resized properly.

Below is the code which I have used to add respective view controller as root view controller in AppDelegate:

```
pagesContainerViewController = [[RWPagesContainerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RWPagesContainerViewController" bundle:nil];
[pagesContainerViewController loadPaginationControlAtIndex:0];
self.window.rootViewController = pagesContainerViewController;
```

Here is the implementation of loadPaginationControlAtIndex method:

```
- (void)loadPaginationControlAtIndex:(RWPaginationView)viewIndex {
    _pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];

    _subviewControllers = @[firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:@[_subviewControllers[viewIndex]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];

    UIView *insertedView = self.pageController.view;
    insertedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[insertedView]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(insertedView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[insertedView]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(insertedView)]];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
}
```

Am I missing anything? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

when the application loads or when your view loads:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

Then add the following method:

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
   [self.pageController setViewControllers:@[_subviewControllers[currentIndex]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];   
}
```